# How to turn this formula into CNF?

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

This formula

$$(p \land q) \lor ( \neg q \lor r) \land ( \neg p \lor r)$$

has the CNF

$$(\neg p \lor q \lor r) \land ( p \lor \neg q \lor r)$$

I understand how CNF works, but I can't seem to figure out my next steps from the above formula. I tried to carrying out distribution. Didn't work. Could anyone suggest a way to get to that CNF expression?

Comment: Please, check formulae. Equivalence does not hold for $p=true;q=true;r=false$.

Comment: I checked with the truth values, it seems to hold for both. I used this website : https://syn-sem.appspot.com/al .

Comment: $\vee$ and $\wedge$ do not associate. So maybe you mean $((p \wedge q) \vee (\neg q \vee r)) \wedge (\neg p \vee r)$, in the first formula